# Jest to vitest migration error; equivalent of moduleNameMapper

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, vitest

I am trying to migrate from jest to Vitest.
at some point, I get this error :
`Syntax Error: Invalid or unexpected token`

It seems one of the packages we have in the project has this line that causes the issue:

```
require("./lib/somefont.woff")
```

I checked jest and jest has this line which resolved the issue:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
```

I was wondering how I can resolve the issue in Vitest?
is there an equivalent of moduleNameMapper in Vitest?

Answer (score 0):

Use `import` to import the font

```
import "./lib/somefont.woff"
```

Try setting `alias` config in `vitest.config.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
    alias: {
      ".*\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: @meisam can you evaluate this solution?